# Confusing JavaScript nested execution result

Tags: javascript, nested-function

I try following simple JavaScript nested code, while the result is confusing.

Anyone can give a detail explanation? Thanks very much.

I am waiting...

```
<script>
  // args = [];

  function foo (param) {
    args= [];
    if (param <= 1) {
      args.push(foo(2));
    } else {
      return param;
    }
  }

  foo(1)
</script>
```

The final ***args*** is ***[]***, I guess the outer ***args*** (is ***[2]***) is overwritten by the nested inner ***args*** (which is ***[]***). Who can give a detail explanation about the result? How is the execution sequences? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"The final args is []"*, I tried the example and the value of `args` after calling `foo(1)` is [2]. Take a look at the console output of this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8hpz18x/)

Comment: I have to say this: you do know you are using a global? Every call to go will work on the same global array. Unsure what is your question, if you debug they code yourself, it will be very clear. Don't post a question without explaining actual versus expected behaviour

Comment: @Juan Mendes, sorry, I edit the code, args should be inside the foo function for my question, I wrongly pasted another test code section.

Comment: @Alvaro Flaño Larrondo, sorry for the question update

Comment: @Hong you still have a global, because you're not using var

Comment: @JuanMendes, yes, I know I am using one global array, while the final result is []. At first glance, args should contain 2 at least, while args is [], I try some other sequences, seems args in inner nested function overwrite the outer ones. What is happening when the nested function return?

Comment: By moving `[]` inside the function, you are resetting it (the global) to an empty array every time the function is called

Comment: @JuanMendes yes, the array will be reset, while for 'args.push(foo(2));', foo(2) will return 2, so 'args.push(foo(2))' seems to be equal to 'args.push(2)', and args will be [2], while from the final actual result [], they are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Dmitry, thanks.

The `args` is a global binding (since you don't use `var`). In first call `foo(1)`, you set it to:

```
args -----> [];
```

Then you add 2 to it by a recursive call. However, when you recursively call `foo` it *rebinding* global `foo` identifier to a new array in memory, *still keeping the old one*.

```
args -----> []  // new array

     -----> [] // old one
```

So you add 2 to the *old one* when return from recursion:

```
args -----> []  // new array

     -----> [2] // old one
```

After exit, `args` is bound to the new one which is empty, and the reference to the old one is missed (it will be GC'ed).

See binding and mutation topics: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-3-1-lexical-environments-common-theory/#name-binding

Answer (score 1):

your code call foo function twice
1. foo(1) is the first call, when foo run the statement

```
if (param <= 1) {
  args.push(foo(2)); // run here for the first call of foo 
} else {
  return param;
}
```

That's similar as

```
if (param <= 1) {
  var foo2= foo(2); // -> trigger the second call of foo
  args.push(foo2); // first element is pushed in args
} else {
  return param;
}
```

In second call of foo(2) param=2 then, foo2=2 on above code,
Finally, you got an array with only an item and args[0]=2

EDIT:

args is not overwrite, you have declare args as local variable of foo function, then when foo(1) was called, it creates a args variable. when foo(2) is called, another args is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
args = [];

  function foo (param) { // param is 1
    if (param <= 1) { // param <= 1 is true
      args.push(foo(2)); // so args is now [foo(2)]
    } else { // ignored
      return param;
    }
  }

  /*
    This is foo(2) is computed
    function foo (param) { // param is 2
    if (param <= 1) { // param <= 1 is false, so this if statement is ignored
      args.push(foo(2));
    } else {
      return param; // returns 2
    }
  }
  */

  foo(1) // args is [2]
```